# What animations are being used in the neom website

Tags: reactjs

I want to know what animation plugins are being used by this website, its build-in ReactJS

[Link to website](https://www.neom.com/en-us/sector/manufacturing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation framework is [GSAP - Greensock](https://greensock.com/gsap/)

[image]

I'm using [wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/) chrome plugin for that.

Comment: Thank's @Dennis Vash

This is a very good framework you shared, I will explorer this

What I am looking for is a horizontal slider, which on drag increase text, and do the background image transactional effect and if possible with a water ripple effect, as shown in example website 

[link](https://www.neom.com/en-us/sector/manufacturing/)

Comment: if you can guide or give exact plugin which does the same